# Limit displayed depth of gradle dependencies task

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, build-dependencies

Using `gradle dependencies` I get a huge list of all dependencies. Showing all dependencies the projects I depend on have. Is it possible to limit the depth of the shown list?
Example:

```
+--- com.company.common:e-common-junit:0.29.0-SNAPSHOT
|    +--- junit:junit:4.11 (*)
|    \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
\--- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.6
     +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6
     \--- log4j:log4j:1.2.17
```

Limited to only `+--- com.company.common:e-common-junit:0.29.0-SNAPSHOT`
From the gradle site:

```
dependencies - Displays all dependencies declared in root project 'projectReports'.
api:dependencies - Displays all dependencies declared in project ':api'.
webapp:dependencies - Displays all dependencies declared in project ':webapp'.
```

It even mentiones that these reports can get large at [this official source](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:listing_dependencies).
Stating that I should use `--configuration`, but as far as my understanding of this article goes it would only limit it to `compile`, `testCompile` and so on, not in depth.
Version in use `gradle 2.11`

Comment: There isn't a gradle way to filter dependency output, but you may be able to use grep to filter out what you don't want to see.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use grep:

- Show only top level dependencies:
  `gradle dependencies --configuration compile | grep -v '|    '`
- Show two levels:
  `gradle dependencies --configuration compile | grep -v '|    |    '`

etc

Comment: I'm working on Powershell, but this still might helps

Comment: I suppose `| select-string -Pattern 'thepattern' -NotMatch` would work

Comment: I can't believe I never thought of this before.